# How to bind to a property of an ObservableCollection Item

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, maui

I have a CollectionView and I would like to bind the Text of the Label to the 'RecipeName'.

It is not working to do: Text="{Binding RecipeName}"

Now it looks like:

[image]

My View looks like:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Recipes}"
                SelectionMode="None">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type x:String}">
            <SwipeView>
                <Grid>
                    <Frame>
                        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                   Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:MainViewModel}}, Path=TapCommand}"
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        <Label Text="{Binding .}" <!-- Here -->
                               FontSize="24"/>
                    </Frame>
                </Grid>
            </SwipeView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

My ViewModel looks like:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    LoadRecipes();
}

private void LoadRecipes()
{
    Recipes = new ObservableCollection<RecipeModel>
    {
        new RecipeModel
        {
            RecipeName = "Rezept 1", // Here
            Ingredients = "Zutaten 1",
            Steps = "Schritte 1"
        },
        new RecipeModel
        {
            RecipeName = "Rezept 2", // Here
            Ingredients = "Zutaten 2",
            Steps = "Schritte 2"
        }
    };
}

[ObservableProperty]
ObservableCollection<RecipeModel> recipes;
```

---

Edit: Thank you very much for your answers. I got it for me: `Text="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type model:RecipeModel}}, Path=RecipeName}"`

Comment: Your solution in your comment from Dec 22, 2022 on the answer of @Jason worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: I got it: `Text="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type model:RecipeModel}}, Path=RecipeName}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This binds the entire object

```
Text="{Binding .}"
```

To bind a specific property

```
Text="{Binding RecipeName}"
```

Note that you can only bind to **public properties**

Comment: As I wrote, it is not working to just bind to the RecipeName because: 

Binding: Property "Recipes" not found on "System.String".

Comment: You did not mention that error in your post.  the DataType attribute on your template is wrong.  it should be RecipeModel, not string

Comment: Thanks, but then I get the following error: Cannot resolve type "http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui:RecipeModel". Can you guess what the problem is ?

Comment: You need to specify the correct namespace

Comment: What would the correct namespace look like (in my case or schematically)?

Comment: I have no idea what namespace your model is in

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/namespaces#declaring-namespaces-for-types

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it: Text="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type model:RecipeModel}}, Path=RecipeName}"

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to set the **BindingContext** of the Text. It seems a little complicated. I give some suggestions to make the use of bindings more clear for your case.

First, set the **BindingContext** of the ContentPage, set it **MainViewModel**. You could set it in .xaml file:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         .....
         xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:BindBindBind">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodel:MainViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

or in code behind .cs file:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BindingContext = new MainViewModel();
}
```

Then for the CollectionView, bind the ItemsSource to the Recipes in the **MainViewModel**. The default **BindingContext** is the same as its parent, that is **MainViewModel** which is set before.

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Recipes}"
        SelectionMode="None">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <SwipeView>
                <Grid>
                    <Frame>
                        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                   Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:MainViewModel}}, Path=TapCommand}"
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        <Label Text="{Binding RecipeName}" FontSize="24"/>
                    </Frame>
                </Grid>
            </SwipeView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

x:DataType for **DataTemplate** is not necessary. **Recipes** is the Collection of RecipeModel instance and **DataTemplate** defines each instance how to display. So for each label, Text property should binds to the RecipeName property of each model instance.

Hope it works for you. If you still have any question, feel free to ask.

For more info, you could refer to [Populate a CollectionView with data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/populate-data?view=net-maui-7.0) and [Data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/?view=net-maui-7.0).